# Отображение двух виджетов вместо одного

Tags: android, android-widgets

Сделал виджет для приложения, но тут появился второй виджет (возможно он был и до создания первого). При попытке прикрепить его на главный экран открывается пустая Activity с возможностью выхода назад. Вопрос: возможно ли его убрать, и если да, то как? Отображается в чистом Android, на MIUI его нет.

[image: Мифический второй виджет]

Comment: Убрать - возможно. Как - удалить код, которым создается этот виджет.

Comment: @Эникейщик так этот виджет и не создаётся моим кодом...

Comment: Наверняка что-нибудь где-нибудь есть. Иначе откуда он берется? Я однажды тоже думал, что дополнительная иконка создается не моим кодом, а это андроид тупит. Потом выяснилось, что тупил все-таки я :)

Comment: @Эникейщик а в чём ваша ошибка то была? Может и мне может помочь?

Comment: В манифесте свойство ``<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`` стояло у двух активити (скопировал все из одной в другую и не убрал). А раз две активити со свойством LAUNCHER, то и две иконки. Может быть, и у вас в манифесте что-нибудь ненужное случайно закралось.

Comment: @Эникейщик благодарю. Дело в том, что на одной из активностей прописан intent-filter с вот этим: <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />